# FFMPEG encoder/settings for TEXT-LEGIBILITY and low file size?

Tags: ffmpeg

I often create long screen-recordings of myself explaining code.

When scrolling text, the movement must be smooth enough.
When static, the edges of text must be crisp for *legibility*.

I tried using CRF (Constant Rate Factor) but the trade-off space does not get me the size compression I believe is possible.

I'd be particularly interested in an encoder that could be "motion-aware". 
e.g. if the video is static, don't store any information. But if there is movement in the video, start storing frames etc. There is a [freeze filter](http://ffmpeg.org/index.html#pr4.2) in the new version, but it looks like its for notifications only.

Does anyone have any good encoders (or settings) they can recommend?

Thanks

Comment: maybe turn up the detail and turn down the frame rate, using variable bit rate for the video would help too. I don't know which options that is.

Comment: See duplicate, particularly the part about CRF encoding. Use a higher CRF to save space. About the `stillimage` tune, it would usually be used to reduce deblocking filtering, but for screencasts you may actually not want to use that. You have to experiment a bit.